# Gif image stuck in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, gif

This is a common issue which I found over the internet, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a ajax loader GIF which is working fine in mozilla firefox but its getting stuck in chrome (ie. Image is not behaving like GIF).

here is the html code snippet-

```
<img id="loader" src="images/loader.gif" />

 $.ajax({
         url:'/myurl',
         type:'POST', 
         data:postArg,  
         dataType:'json',
         async:false,      
         success:function(as){
                    $('#loader').hide();
         }
        });
```

This is the ajax code which is returning response in around 10-15 seconds so I want to implement a loader until response is returned.

This is the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbLP.jpg

Expecting someone to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sajalsuraj as of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated. remove this line async:false, see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You are making a *synchronous* request. That blocks your entire browser while the request is in progress. In Chrome, this also blocks rendering. That it works at all in Firefox is a fluke.

There is virtually *never* a reason to use `async: false`. You should remove that line and let your **A**JAX be **A**synchronous.

Comment: Suggest instead to use `.differed` or `.queue` jQuery methods to replace `async: false`